# How to upload images to imgur using knitr and R Markdown after "Empty reply from server" error?

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to upload images from a R Markdown knitr document in RStudio 0.96.
I've tried running the [following code](https://raw.github.com/yihui/knitr/master/inst/examples/knitr-upload.Rmd) that is meant to be a minimal example.
However, I get the following error message:

```
List of 1
 $ message: logi FALSE

label: md-cars (with options) 
List of 1
 $ message: logi FALSE

Error in process_file(text) : 
  Quitting from lines 31-34: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Empty reply from server
Calls: knit -> process_file

Execution halted

knitr terminated with status 1
```

- What might cause this error message?
- How can I upload images to Imgur using knitr and avoid this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2665814/180892) suggested that the error may be related to firewalls and proxy servers. When I  tested the above code I was at work at a university, where there are such things. When I tried it at home over a different network, the code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include this line in your code:

`opts_knit$set(upload.fun = imgur_upload)`

Comment: Thanks. I agree that is required. and it's a good point to make. My specific error only results when this setting is already activated.