# cURL returns Empty reply from server

Tags: curl, soap

I am using following command but in return I am getting "curl: (52) Empty reply from server". Please see the code and advise what change it requires.

```
curl -k --user "USERNAME:PASSWORD" --request POST --header "Content-type: text/xml" --header "SOAPAction:http://EXAMPLE.COM/b2b/2014/02/IB2BService/SubmitMessage" --data @actual.xml https://EXAMPLE.COM/B2BGatewayService/B2BGatewayService.svc
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924434/curl-error-52-empty-reply-from-server
Additionally, you have flagged this as a `PHP` question which it is not as curl works independently.