# PUT with cURL couchDB

Tags: database, bash, curl, couchdb, put

I am trying to create a database with `curl` from the command line on Windows using this command:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/test_database.
```

I receive this response:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I am able to see all the created databases (`curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/_all_dbs`) and i can also use GET to see information for a specific database created from Futon interface, but PUT doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried to enter the `curl` command from win-bash command line. I got the same response.

What else should i try?

Comment: Not related to CouchDB, but perhaps this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924434/curl-error-52-empty-reply-from-server

Comment: I ran that same command on Linux and it worked just fine for me, what version of CouchDB are you running? (not sure how cURL varies on Windows)