# How to fix `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` response on localhost?

Tags: curl, localhost

The problem is in my setting, because I am accessing localhost.

When I execute in terminal:

```
curl http://localhost
```

The response is:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

But it should say:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

**UPDATE:**

When I execute

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

The response is:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

**UPDATE(2)**

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

> COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
>
> acwebseca 42015 root   36u  IPv4 0x2e120362d0318e9b      0t0  TCP
>
> 192.168.0.109:52299->151.101.129.69:http (ESTABLISHED)
>   ...

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl Error 52 Empty reply from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924434/curl-error-52-empty-reply-from-server)

Comment: @kbariotis thanks, but it doesn't help me

Comment: Yeap, I may rushed to flag your question. Why are you expecting to see curl :(7)?

Comment: @kbariotis because on my friend's computer it returns (7)

Comment: Do you have any process running on port 80?

Comment: Ok, obviously there is something running and listening to your local 80 port. Like a proxy or a server. Can you remember if you have started a service or something?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 yes you are right, but after I kill it it appears again(

Comment: @kbariotis I updated the question

Comment: The process restarts automatically?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 yes, I don't understand what is it

Comment: [`netstat -tulpn | grep --color :80`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-what-running-on-port-80-command/)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I found the process and killed the programme. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I had application which was constantly restarting on port 80. I uninstalled the application and it solved it

Answer (score 0):

Check port conflict with following command (Mac) and close applications using same port:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
lsof -n -iTCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
lsof -n -i:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

Substitute `$PORT` with the port number or a comma-separated list of port numbers.

Prepend `sudo` (followed by a space) if you need information on ports below #1024.