# curl error 52 when accessing https when wget works

Tags: ssl, curl, wget, snom

I'm trying to access the web interface of a [Snom D315](http://wiki.snom.com/D315/Documentation) phone via curl (7.62.0 on macOS), but I keep getting error 52 (`CURLE_GOT_NOTHING`):

```
$ curl --insecure --user admin:password https://172.16.99.61/settings.xml
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Interesting factoids:

- access via HTTP works as expected
- the page (HTTPS) opens just fine in a browser or via wget (1.19.5)
- it also works on older [Snom D300](http://wiki.snom.com/Snom300/Documentation) devices (with a different firmware of course)

Any help is appreciated!

P.S.: I've read through the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924434/curl-error-52-empty-reply-from-server) but to no avail. I've also confirmed this behaviour with a different D315 and curl 7.52.1 on Debian and updated the phone's firmware to the lastest version.

---

### Details

#### curl

Here's the output of `curl --trace-ascii --trace-time --insecure --user admin:password https://172.16.99.61/settings.xml`:

```
11:31:18.201318 == Info:   Trying 172.16.99.61...
11:31:18.201651 == Info: TCP_NODELAY set
11:31:18.202233 == Info: Connected to 172.16.99.61 (172.16.99.61) port 443 (#0)
11:31:18.205540 == Info: ALPN, offering http/1.1
11:31:18.205555 == Info: WARNING: disabling hostname validation also disables SNI.
11:31:18.267158 == Info: TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
11:31:18.267184 == Info: ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
11:31:18.270517 == Info: Server certificate: xxxxxxxxxxxx
11:31:18.270615 == Info: Server certificate: Snom Phone 1
11:31:18.270712 == Info: Server certificate: Snom Technology AG CA
11:31:18.270730 == Info: Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
11:31:18.270784 => Send header, 131 bytes (0x83)
0000: GET /settings.xml HTTP/1.1
001c: Host: 172.16.99.61
0030: Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
005b: User-Agent: curl/7.62.0
0074: Accept: */*
0081: 
11:31:18.391320 == Info: Empty reply from server
11:31:18.391337 == Info: Connection #0 to host 172.16.99.61 left intact
```

And this is the corresponding log from the phone in question:

```
Nov 13 11:31:17.394 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP accepting from Tls:172.16.1.167:65215
Nov 13 11:31:17.395 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 944/443 accepted from Tls:172.16.1.167:65215
Nov 13 11:31:17.395 [ERROR ] TLS: BIO_new_bio_pair code 336396495, error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown
Nov 13 11:31:17.395 [ERROR ] TLS: BIO_new_bio_pair code 336396495, error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown
Nov 13 11:31:17.396 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 handshake start
Nov 13 11:31:17.396 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 before/accept initialization (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.396 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 944/443 connected
Nov 13 11:31:17.399 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read client hello A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.400 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write server hello A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.401 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write certificate A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.401 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write certificate request A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.401 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 flush data (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.408 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read client certificate A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.442 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read client key exchange A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.442 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read certificate verify A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.444 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read finished A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.444 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write change cipher spec A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.445 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write finished A (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.445 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 flush data (0)
Nov 13 11:31:17.458 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 handshake done
Nov 13 11:31:17.458 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 Flag SSL3_FLAGS_NO_RENEGOTIATE_CIPHERS set.
Nov 13 11:31:17.458 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0xc44330 SetHandshakeFinished()
Nov 13 11:31:17.463 [INFO ] PHN: WEB: Request 944/131/0: GET /settings.xml HTTP/1.1
Nov 13 11:31:17.464 [INFO ] PHN: WEB: 944 Basic authentication.
Nov 13 11:31:17.582 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 944/443 disconnecting
Nov 13 11:31:17.583 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 944/443 disconnected
Nov 13 11:31:17.583 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 944/443 deleted
```

#### wget

Here's the output of `wget --verbose --no-check-certificate --server-response -O- https://admin:password@172.16.99.61/settings.xml >/dev/null`:

```
-2018-11-13 11:34:35--  https://admin:*password*@172.16.99.61/settings.xml
Connecting to 172.16.99.61:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify 172.16.99.61's certificate, issued by 'emailAddress=security@snom.com,CN=Snom Phone 1,O=Snom Technology AG,L=Berlin,ST=Berlin,C=DE':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
    WARNING: certificate common name 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' doesn't match requested host name '172.16.99.61'.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="snom"
  Content-Type: text/plain
  Content-Length: 22
Authentication selected: Basic realm="snom"
Reusing existing connection to 172.16.99.61:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
  Server: snom embedded
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Content-Length: 110173
Length: 110173 (108K) [text/xml]
Saving to: 'STDOUT'
2018-11-13 11:34:36 (2.39 MB/s) - written to stdout [110173/110173]
```

And this is the log from the phone:

```
Nov 13 11:34:35.023 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP accepting from Tls:172.16.1.167:49672
Nov 13 11:34:35.024 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 974/443 accepted from Tls:172.16.1.167:49672
Nov 13 11:34:35.024 [ERROR ] TLS: BIO_new_bio_pair code 336396495, error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown
Nov 13 11:34:35.025 [ERROR ] TLS: BIO_new_bio_pair code 336396495, error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown
Nov 13 11:34:35.025 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 handshake start
Nov 13 11:34:35.025 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 before/accept initialization (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.025 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 974/443 connected
Nov 13 11:34:35.028 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read client hello A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.029 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write server hello A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.030 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write certificate A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.030 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write certificate request A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.030 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 flush data (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.034 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read client certificate A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.069 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read client key exchange A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.069 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read certificate verify A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.072 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 read finished A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.073 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write session ticket A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.073 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write change cipher spec A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.074 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 write finished A (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.074 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SSL_accept/0 SSLv3 flush data (0)
Nov 13 11:34:35.074 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 handshake done
Nov 13 11:34:35.074 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 Flag SSL3_FLAGS_NO_RENEGOTIATE_CIPHERS set.
Nov 13 11:34:35.075 [DEBUG2] TLS: 0x8dd4c0 SetHandshakeFinished()
Nov 13 11:34:35.079 [INFO ] PHN: WEB: Request 974/154/0: GET /settings.xml HTTP/1.1
Nov 13 11:34:35.080 [INFO ] PHN: WEB: 974 Basic authentication.
Nov 13 11:34:35.080 [INFO ] PHN: Authentication triggered. Set flag back.
Nov 13 11:34:35.082 [INFO ] PHN: WEB: Request 974/197/0: GET /settings.xml HTTP/1.1
Nov 13 11:34:35.083 [INFO ] PHN: WEB: 974 Basic authentication.
Nov 13 11:34:35.251 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 974/443 disconnected
Nov 13 11:34:35.251 [DEBUG2] PHN: WEB: HTTP 974/443 deleted
```

Comment: Although I don't believe this will be the solution (the handshake going to its end correctly), try with the [--no-alpn](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--no-alpn) option

Comment: I did try that, makes no difference (other than that log message disappearing).

Comment: I just see 3 painfull methods for your problem : looking in the whole curl bug database, trying all of the --no-something options, making a network capture with hope that you can decrypt it (use a non FS cipher suite). Maybe, try a HEAD or OPTIONS http method to see how it behaves. Does the password contain a _very_ special character (= : ?) ?

Comment: I already tried all --no-something options that might be applicable without success. The password consists of alphanumeric characters only :(

Comment: Did you try an openssl s_client command to see how it behaves ? Interestingly, you can then send your request built from text only (GET / HTTP/1.1 Authorization: Basic ***==  .... )

Comment: Oh, sweet - I wasn't aware of that tool!

Comment: If wget does what you want, why bother with curl ? Is curl possibly linked with OPenSSL and wget possibly with GnuTLS ?

Comment: Because I need to access the page using the Zabbix HTTP Agent, which uses curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this is interesting: manually adding the `Connection: keep-alive` header makes everything work:

```
$ curl -sSL -D - -o /dev/null --insecure -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --user admin:xxxxx https://172.16.99.61/settings.xml
Wed Nov 14 11:18:13 CET 2018
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Server: snom embedded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 110192
```

Whereas without it, it doesn't:

```
$ curl -sSL -D - -o /dev/null --insecure --user admin:xxxxx https://172.16.99.61/settings.xml
Wed Nov 14 11:19:53 CET 2018
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: I will, but I have to wait another hour :)