# Shell script to poll whether a service is up

Tags: bash, shell

I wanted to know if there is any error in the code

```
while true
do
    var=$(curl http://${SERVER_HOST}:8060/vmc/vdisizer/api/v1/health) && echo "Got Reply from $SERVER_HOST" || echo "Curl failed to connect to $SERVER_HOST" 
    if [ "$var" -eq "OK" ]
    then
        echo "Success"
        break
    fi
done
```

This does not work and I get the following error -

```
int-tester_1     | curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I want this to continuously poll the service till the service replies "OK" and then break from the loop.

On changing -eq to = , I get the following error -

```
int-tester_1     | + var=OK
int-tester_1     | Got Reply from 10.2.223.87
int-tester_1     | + echo 'Got Reply from 10.2.223.87'
int-tester_1     | + '[' = OK ']'
int-tester_1     | ./run_itests.sh: line 33: [: =: unary operator expected
```

Comment: It's not causing the current problem, but `-eq` does integer comparison, not string comparison. Inside a `[ ]` test, use `=` for string comparison. Also, be aware that web content generally use CRLF line endings, so if the reply is nominally `OK`, it'll actually be `OK\r\n` (where `\r` represents carriage return and `\n` represents newline); the `$()` will trim the `\n` but leave the `\r`, and the carriage return will cause the two strings to be unequal.

Comment: Got the following error - 
` 
int-tester_1     | + var=OK
int-tester_1     | Got Reply from 10.2.223.87
int-tester_1     | + echo 'Got Reply from 10.2.223.87'
int-tester_1     | + '[' = OK ']'
int-tester_1     | ./run_itests.sh: line 33: [: =: unary operator expected 
`

Comment: Made the change

Comment: The updated test isn't actually getting the `$var` variable -- what exactly is that line now? Also, what's that `echo`?

Comment: In general, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is the best place to start when debugging bash scripts.

Comment: Line 33 is if [ "$var" -eq "OK" ]

Comment: echo is from the answer below

Comment: Oh, that explains it. When you put the `var=` part inside `( )`, it runs in a subshell and the assignment to `var applies only in that subshell. Remove the parentheses.

Comment: I updated it in the question, is that correct?

Comment: Oh that worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Issue could be with following command
Is SERVER_HOST getting populated

```
curl http://${SERVER_HOST}:8060/vmc/vdisizer/api/v1/health
```

also 
can you have

```
(var=$(curl http://${SERVER_HOST}:8060/vmc/vdisizer/api/v1/health)) && echo "Got Reply from $SERVER_HOST" || echo "Curl failed to connect to $SERVER_HOST"
```

does `curl http://10.2.223.87:8060/vmc/vdisizer/api/v1/health`
get output ?

something similar to [Curl Error 52 Empty reply from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924434/curl-error-52-empty-reply-from-server)

Comment: Yes SERVER_HOST is getting populated. On the terminal I can see curl http://10.2.223.87:8060/vmc/vdisizer/api/v1/health