# Rundeck job returns curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: rundeck

Rundeck job returns "curl: (52) Empty reply from server" if the jobs takes 2 minutes or more.
Also part of the error "SSH command execution error: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status 52"
We have a rundeck job (curl cmd) that executes on a Linux 7 server that for the majority of the time returns a "success" for the completion of the job.
However sometimes it will return "failed" if the job runs 2 minutes or more.
A value for "5m" has been added to the job "Timeout" on the configuration.
The job actually is successful but rundeck still returns the "failed" status.
When comparing the successful against failed logs I notice some extra steps in the failed log which pushes it past the 2 minutes time.

Any ideas why the failed status as mentioned above?

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: Could you run your job on debug mode and share the output? (please hide or change any pontentially sensitive information) Also, did you try to do same job manually from the Rundeck server? Looks like a network problem (check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924434/what-is-the-curl-error-52-empty-reply-from-server)

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your curl command against the web server, usually happens when you call using `HTTP` against an `HTTPS` based service. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42837622/10426011). Another possibility is a [network problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2665814/10426011).