# Can I get response of curl through POD IP address (instead of host address) while using nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am using `nginx ingress controller` below is the ingress rule file for 2 services:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - rewrite.bar.com.com
    secretName: ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-service-1/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service-1
            port:
              number: 36995
      - path: /my-service-2/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service-2
            port:
              number: 32243
```

Now using below command through shell of service-2 I can curl to the service-1 api endpoint, here I need to pass host ('wire.com') which is TLS enabled as well,

```
curl --resolve wire.com:443:10.22.148.179 https://wire.com:32243/GetData
```

Above curl using host address give me response successfully, no issue here!

Now I am using IP address of the POD instead of host address, but this won't give me response, it's always give error like `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. Here `10.22.148.179` is my ingress public IP address and `10.2.0.58` is my POD IP address.

```
curl --resolve enabledservices-dev-aks.honeywell.com:443:10.22.148.179 http//10.2.0.58:32243/GetData
```

My goal to hit the POD/service api end point through IP address, is this possible with context of Ingress integrated?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by `through shell of service-2`? Also which POD's IP are you using? Ingress one or pod's IP behind the service-1? I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve this way. All traffic should go through ingress and let ingress do the routing and etc.

Comment: Yes I understand traffic should route through Ingress and no issue with that. For some of my debug purpose I want to hit the app end point of service 1 from shell of any other pod. I have multiple relplica of service 1 and I want to hit specific replica with IP address.  Is this possible?

Comment: You have two options: 1 - via ingress, 2 - direct service/pod-ip or even by dns-name without using ingress at all. See [dns in kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). So in other words simple `curl service-1.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local:PORT` and whatever else you need.

Comment: Thanks. Still I am getting 52 empty response with `url service-1.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local:PORT`. How to access through direct service/pod-ip> could you please give more input

Comment: Well, you need to `curl POD_IP:PORT` from the another pod which is inside the cluster. DNS was for services mostly, but for direct usage `cluster-ip` is available inside. This is actually why `ingress` is used - to expose services with `cluster-ip` outside the cluster so `ingress` is a one access point to the cluster.

Comment: Also please check if [this is the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42837622/15537201)

Comment: Thanks! this is what I tried `$ curl 10.22.148.212:32243/GetData` from other POD shell, but NOT sure what's wrong with this, always getting `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` :(

Comment: @moonkotte, Finally WORKS with this, `curl -k https://10.22.148.212:32243/GetData`, -k and https. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this from comments to answer.

---

The issue was curl request and HTTP protocol used while the server is serving by HTTPS. This is the reason of `(52) Empty reply from server` error.

Request by curl should be done by specifying the protocol like:

```
curl https://test.example.com:8888
```

---

`Ingress` is used as a single entry point to the cluster so all inside services can be exposed internally in the cluster using `cluster-ip` service type - see [kubernetes service types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

If any inside service/pod is required to be tested from inside the cluster, request should be executed from the cluster to be able to hit a `cluster-ip` since `cluster-ip` is only accessible within the cluster.