# why socks5 protocol in `http_proxy` lead "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"?

Tags: http, curl, proxy, socks

I use the shadowsocks and the proxy client is called Trojan-Qt5. I am testing whether I can visit [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in terminal.

when I set the environment variable `http_proxy` to http protocol

```bash
export "http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:58591"
```

the command `curl -Iv www.google.com` return normal response.

However, when I set `http_proxy` to socks5 protocol

```bash
export "http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:51837"
```

it returns

```bash
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

[image: screenshot of the iterm2]

I just want to know why changing to socks5 protocol lead to the problem?

By the way, the question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924434/what-is-the-curl-error-52-empty-reply-from-server).

Comment: Adding `-v` might shed some more light on it, but it sounds like maybe the proxy isn't sending data through properly from the server to curl.

Comment: @DanielStenberg thx for the suggestion, I have adjusted the question. I think the proxy client have sent the data, but the server replied with neither response header nor response body.

Comment: No header and no response, that's not a valid HTTP response so that's exactly why curl says "empty reply from server". Since you got the reply when using the HTTP proxy, I would say it hints on your socks proxy doing the wrong thing.