# MarkLogic XDMP-INVZIP: Invalid zip file while trying to import the configuration zip file

Tags: curl, marklogic, marklogic-10

I export the cluster configuration file through management console "http://localhost:8002/manage/v3?format=zip" and try to import through curl command but it return below error can you suggest correct way to import the configuration file with zip format.

MarkLogic version -10

```
curl -v -X POST --anyauth --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/zip" -d@package2.zip 'http://localhost:8002/manage/v3'
```

Error:

> ```
> { [325 bytes data]
> 100 41563  100   325  100 41238   3457   428k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  431k<error 
> xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error">
>   <status-code>500</status-code>
>   <status>Internal Server Error</status>
>   <message-code>XDMP-INVZIP</message-code>
>   <message>XDMP-INVZIP: xdmp:zip- 
> manifest(binary{"504b030414de958bb6ea8bb74116f0faffc3d2b0d0ed4b1ada3f3ee89addae7e..."})
> -- 
> Invalid zip file</message>
> </error>
>
> * Connection #1 to host localhost left intact
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The example command provided on the [/REST/POST/manage/v3](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v3) documentation is incorrect. I have filed a bug to get it corrected.

The zip file is a binary artifact, and is getting mangled.

Rather than `-d`, you should apply the [`--binary-data`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) option.

```
curl -v -X POST --anyauth --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/zip" --binary-data @package2.zip 'http://localhost:8002/manage/v3'
```

Comment: Thanks @Mads Hansen, but the i'm getting below error and no changes in cluster config also any fix for this?
curl: (52) Empty reply from server  
* TCP_NODELAY set * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8002 (#0)
> POST /manage/v3 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8002
> User-Agent: curl/7.63.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/zip
>
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     0* Empty reply from server
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Comment: Is your 8002 appserver HTTPS? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42837622/14419

Comment: No it's only HTTP